# jquery on change and input function run multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-selectors

In my code there are 140 selectors and 2 events(change , input)

```
$("#selector1, #selector2, #selector3, ...... #selector139, #selector140").on('change input',function(e){
    console.log('test')//it returns 28 times  
    //My jquery code
}
```

When i decrease number of selectors the return times also decrease but i need all of selectors.

I used these methods

```
$("#selector1, #selector2, #selector3, ...... #selector139, #selector140").off('change input').on('change input',function(e){
    console.log('test')//it returns 28 times  
    //My jquery code
}
```

but input event didn't work

```
$("#selector1, #selector2, #selector3, ...... #selector139, #selector140").on('change input', function(e){ 
 if(e.handled !== true) 
{
    //Code 
    e.handled = true;
}

});
```

but this method also didn't work
I used `one()` function but it didn't work properly.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Thanks !!!

Comment: Why not use classes instead? You shouldn't have that many IDs

Comment: Exactly what I was going to suggest @CertainPerformance

Comment: All elements are `input` ? if not, of course input event not working.

Comment: All elements are inputs 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's better to use `class` instead.
just add a class to your inputs like this :

```
<input class="someclass" type="text" />
```

then you could easily add the event listeners like this:

```
$('.someclass').on('input change',function() {
    //do what you want
});
```